# Missing artifact com.google.guava:guava:bundle:18.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, guava

I'm using Eclipse Luna. When i add "guava" through maven i'm getting this error

```
Missing artifact com.google.guava:guava:bundle:18.0
```

I have followed [Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.guava%7Cguava%7C18.0%7Cbundle). I updated same, but still getting the same error.

My dependency in pom.xml file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

there is no type bundle, change it to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/

Comment: seems to be some maven eclipse issue